# Angularjs: create a link for download different types of file

Tags: angularjs, download, base64

Good day!

I can't resolve my problem - create link to download attachment. 
A file I receive from SOAP service in xml and consequently I must create a link to download file.

What I have now:

In controller:

```js
//creating comments
for (var index in $scope.comments){
                    var com = $scope.comments[index]
                    if (com.z2AF_Work_Log01_attachmentName !== undefined){
                      var a         = document.createElement('a');
                      a.target      = '_blank';
                      a.download    = com.z2AF_Work_Log01_attachmentName;
                      a.innerText   = com.z2AF_Work_Log01_attachmentName;

                      var blob = new Blob([ atob(com.z2AF_Work_Log01_attachmentData) ], 
                        { type : 'zip' });
                      //com.href  = (window.URL || window.webkitURL).createObjectURL( blob );
                      a.href = (window.URL || window.webkitURL).createObjectURL( blob );;
                      com.attachment_link = a.outerHTML;

                    }
                  }
```

Links created, but if I have not plain text (csv) a file after download is broken. When I download csv - all fine.

In template:

```html
.attach ng-bind-html="comment.attachment_link | notSanit"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 3 days research I found the solution:

```js
var decodeString = unescape(atob(attchment_data));
var ab = new ArrayBuffer(decodeString.length);
var ia = new Uint8Array(ab);
for (var i = 0; i < decodeString.length; i++) {
  ia[i] = decodeString.charCodeAt(i);
}

var blob = new Blob([ab]);

href =  (window.URL || window.webkitURL).createObjectURL( blob );
```